# Distinguish CodePush updates by buildNumber/versionCode

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

Is it possible that two builds, with the same version, but different build numbers(iOS)/versionCode(Android), to target different CodePush updates?

For example, I have a React Native application, and I have built two iOS builds:

- 1.0.1(2)
- 1.0.1(3)

Currently, both builds will fetch the latest CodePush update for version 1.0.1. But can it be done that these builds fetch different CodePush updates, according to their build number?

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: No, we are using clean react-native, and react-native-code-push library.

Comment: Hi! did you got this solved?